# $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not the root of a quadratic with rational coefficients?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

How can one show that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not a root of a quadratic with rational coefficients?

It is clear that if $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is the root of such a quadratic, then it is also the root of a quadratic with integer coefficients. This reduces the problem a bit, but I don't see where one can go from here.

Answer (score 6):

I'll take it for granted that $2^{1/3}$ is irrational.  (The proof is essentially the same as for the irrationality of $2^{1/2}$.)

Now suppose $2^{1/3}$ is the root of a quadratic polynomial with rational coefficients, $x^2+bx+c=0$.  Then we can write

$$2^{2/3}=-b2^{1/3}-c$$

Multiplying by $2^{1/3}$ gives

$$\begin{align}
2&=-b2^{2/3}-c2^{1/3}\\
&=-b(-b2^{1/3}-c)-c2^{1/3}\\
&=(b^2-c)2^{1/3}+bc
\end{align}$$

Since $2^{1/3}$ is irrational, we must have $c=b^2$, which leaves $2=bc=b^3$, so that $b=2^{1/3}$, which contradicts the assumption that $b$ is rational.

Answer (score 3):

It's already the root of some obvious cubic over ${\mathbb Z}$; that cubic is irreducible (why?), so it is the minimum polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{2}$; therefore no polynomial over ${\mathbb Q}$ of degree smaller than 3 has $\sqrt[3]{2}$ as root.

Comment: It wasn't me, but I'd guess it was because someone who would ask this question, surely doesn't know about fields, minimum polynomials and the like.

Comment: The OP seems to know about Gauss' Lemma, though. Minimum polynomials might be too much, I agree.

Comment: What the OP said doesn't imply that he nows Gauss' lemma. He is just saying if there is such a polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x]$, then one can multiply by a scalar to get a polynomial with integers coefficients. He didn't say anything about irreducibility.

Comment: @GitGud Hmm, that's true as well. Ah well, maybe the OP will learn from my answer that once you know a bit of theory, this type of question becomes very easy.

Comment: @GitGud Both your comments are accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the ring of polynomials $\def\Q{\mathbb{Q}}\Q[X]$ and the subset
$$
I=\{f\in\Q[X]:f(\sqrt[3]{2})=0\}
$$
I claim there exists a unique monic polynomial $p(X)\in I$ such that every polynomial $f\in I$ is of the form $f(X)=p(X)q(X)$ for some $q\in\Q[X]$.

In order to prove this we only need to know the division algorithm in $\Q[X]$: given $A(X)$ and $B(X)$ in $\Q[X]$, with $B\ne0$, there exist $Q(X)$ and $R(X)$ such that 
$$
A(X)=B(X)Q(X)+R(X)\text{ and the degree of $R$ is less than the degree of $B$}.
$$
(we consider the degree of the zero polynomial to be $-\infty$).

In order to prove the claim about $I$, we just take a nonzero monic polynomial $p$ of minimum degree in $I$. Such a polynomial exists, because $X^3-2\in I$. Now, if $f\in I$, we can write
$$
f(X)=p(X)q(X)+R(X)
$$
where the degree of $R$ is less than the degree of $p$. Since
$$
0=f(\sqrt[3]{2})=p(\sqrt[3]{2})q(\sqrt[3]{2})+R(\sqrt[3]{2})=0\cdot q(\sqrt[3]{2})+R(\sqrt[3]{2})
$$
we conclude that $R(\sqrt[3]{2})=0$, so $R\in I$. By the minimality of the degree of $p$, the only possibility is that $R=0$. The uniqueness of $p$ is almost obvious: if $p_1$ is another nonzero monic polynomial in $I$, then $p-p_1\in I$ would have degree less than both, so it must be zero.

Now $p$ is irreducible: if $p=p_1p_2$, where $p_1$ and $p_2$ can be chosen monic, $$
0=p(\sqrt[3]{2})=p_1(\sqrt[3]{2})p_2(\sqrt[3]{2})
$$
so at least one of the two factors must by in $I$ and, again, by the minimality of the degree of $p$ one of the two factors is $p$.

Now assume $p$ has degree less than $3$; then
$$
X^3-2=p(X)q(X)
$$
for some $q\in\Q[X]$. This is impossible, because $X^3-2$ is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion. In particular $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is irrational.

---

This is standard theory. The set $I$, that can be defined for any algebraic number (that is, one that is root of a polynomial with rational coefficients), is an ideal of $\Q[X]$. The argument above can be applied to any ideal of $\Q[X]$ to show it is generated by a polynomial (we say that $\Q[X]$ is a principal ideal domain).

In the case of $I=\{f\in\Q[X]:f(r)=0\}$, where $r$ is an algebraic number, this ideal is also maximal and the generator (the unique nonzero monic polynomial of minimal degree) is called the *minimal polynomial* of $r$. Such a minimal polynomial is irreducible. Actually, it is not difficult to show that the minimal polynomial of $r$ can be characterized as the unique irreducible monic polynomial having $r$ among its roots.

Comment: If you're going to teach the OP about minimal polynomials from scratch, you should probably mention their name, so the OP doesn't think you made them up just to solve this one problem.

Comment: @JackM You're right.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a proof using only the fundamental theorem of algebra and polynomial long division (Euclid's algorithm), without using minimal polynomials or irreducibility criteria:

---

Let $p(x)$ be a rational-coefficient polynomial for which $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is a root.

Put $q(x)=x^3-2$ and consider $g(x)= \mbox{gcd}(p(x), q(x))$, obtained via Euclid's algorithm.

$g(x)$ has rational coefficients since $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ do, and $\deg(g(x))\le \deg(p(x))$. $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ share a root, so $g(x)$ has degree at least $1$. Denote the constant term of $g(x)$ by $a_0$.

The constant term of a polynomial is, up to a sign, the product of its roots and its leading coefficient*. $g(x)$ divides $q(x)$ so its roots are a subset of the roots of $q(x)$, which are the complex numbers $\omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3$ each with modulus $\sqrt[3]{2}$. So taking modulus, we have $|a_0|= |a_n| \left(\sqrt[3]{2}\right)^n$ where $n$ is the degree of $g(x)$, and $a_n$ the leading coefficient of $g(x)$. In particular we get that $\left(\sqrt[3]{2}\right)^n$ is rational.

$\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not rational, so $n\neq 1$. And $\left(\sqrt[3]{2}\right)^2$ is not rational, so $n\neq 2$. So $n\ge 3$.

Since $n=\deg (g(x)) \le \deg (p(x))$ we obtain that $p(x)$ is of degree at least $3$.

---

*Proof: Expand $a_nx^n+...+a_1 x + a_0 = a_n(x-r_1)\cdots(x-r_n)$ and compare constant terms: $a_0 = a_n(-1)^nr_1\cdots r_n$.

Answer (score 0):

$x = \sqrt[3]{2}$ or $x^3-2 = 0$ but by the RRT....